# Grouping by distinct ID and process each group via map or foreach Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Folks,

Need suggestion and help in grouping logic and processing of over 10M records. Processing has to be done by grouping on ID. Each group has to be feed into a forEach or map and transform method has to be called on each group.  A group can contain 10-500 records    |

```
|      ID2    |        senderID    |        targetID    |  app  |
+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
|1            |                  FG|                  OM| R-type|
|1            |                  FG|                  OM| R-type|
|1            |         DMA.3.450.5|SILO303.FG.RECV.3...|    FRD|
|2            |                  OM|                  FG| F-Type|
|3            |              EFG-NY|             ETP2EFG|    EFG|
|3            |SILO303.FG.RECV.3...|         DMA.3.450.5|    FRD|
|2            |                  OM|                  FG| F-Type|
|3            |          NEXTGEN_CA|              E-Type|    EFG|
|2            |         DMA.3.450.5|TSX.FG.ROUT.3.500.57|     FG|
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--
```

So ID2 is the coulmn i need to group my records on. I need to make groups according to ID2 like below and feed to a transform method one by one.

```
finalFeed.rdd.map(Groups => (transform(Groups))).collect.toList
```

But i do not think there is a way to do this. As passing dataframe to methods in a loop does not execute on drivers.

What are the options to move around such a situation.

The groups that i pass to my `transform(Groups)` method will be further grouped according to senderID,targetID,app and then filter and all will take place to see  if group is valid or not.

Shall i convert this DF to some collection and then pass to my transform method. But then i wont be able to apply filter and all as they are dataframe methods.

Help needed folks. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is with your `collect` and `toList` and not with the transform itself.

Comment: That can be removed also. Can we send groups to transform method. I donot thinl we can pass dataframe to methods . It will work on driver only